# Live tracking session variables from db

Tags: php, mysql, session, joomla, tracking

I've been looking for an easy way to track my current session variables on my desktop in order to have an eye on them.

My website uses Joomla and session variables are stored in MySQL by PHP.

What I'd like to achieve is a 'widget' or 'snippet' which could show on my Windows 7 desktop current session variables, and how they change during a visit on the website.

In fact the session state is stored in a table like:

```
session_id  varchar(32)
data        varchar(20480)
userid      int(11)
```

So let say one solution could be retrieving first two columns by my userid with a SQL query and parsing 'data' column, which is in JSON format, into an 'snippet' object.

I don't know how to write widget/snippets and I don't expect anybody to write me one, I just wonder if such thing exist to make my developing easier.

Comment: Temporarily to track a session state I have to refresh phpmyadmin manually, which is really annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's been long time since I asked this question. So far, the best option I've found was [PHP Quick Profiler](http://particletree.com/features/php-quick-profiler/) tunned a bit up for Joomla Framework. Soon, I gonna post a tutorial how to implement this for Joomla. Should anybody want to hurry me up do not hesitate :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to hack together something, I've got a couple of crude suggestions.

- Write a simple SQL query ordered by date, throw in some HTML and add javascript to auto refresh the page, say every 30 seconds. Now you just need a tab open to monitor your sessions.
- The same thing as above but instead of HTML, output XML in the feed format. Then use any feed reader software which usually has desktop widgets and alerts etc.

Good luck!